# JQueryUI AutoComplete: Cookie not passed in IE9

Tags: jquery-ui, cookies

I have the below codes which works fine in Firefox, Opera & Chrome but not in IE9:

```
$("#Number").autocomplete({
    source: "GetData?Type=Number",
    minLength: 3,
    delay: 300
});
```

Through Fiddler, I found that in IE9, cookie is not passed automatically in the call to GetData.

How do I add the cookie to the AutoComplete request?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've got it working by putting in the full path for the request:

```
source: "http://mydomain/GetData?Type=Number",
```

Silly me. Spent almost half a day on such simple issue.